# Replacement moderator proposal

Tags: discussion, status-completed, moderators

As some of you know, I've joined Stack Exchange today as a core developer. As such, I'll be stepping down as a moderator. It's been a fun four years, and I'll miss this community a lot.

In exiting my moderation role, I've been thinking about whom I'd like to see join on as a moderator in my place. I've worked a lot with [Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner) on this site, and he is one of the most level-headed people I've had the pleasure of interacting with, anywhere on the Internet. I wholeheartedly endorse his appointment as a moderator.

Martin has asked me to write this post, to solicit views from the community about whom they'd like to see as a moderator. I should have thought to do this before, so I really appreciate his suggestion.

Comments welcome.

Comment: Martin is fantastic, couldn't agree more with the comments about level-headedness.

Comment: Congratulations on your new job! And excellent choice for moderator. :)

Answer (score 40):

I disagree with this nomination.

He'll do such a good job of being a moderator that he'll make all the rest of us look bad.

:D

In all seriousness, if @MartinBüttner isn't a good candidate for moderator, I don't know who is. He's extremely active on the main site, meta, and chat, and he's done volumes of work to help welcome new users, hash out policies on meta, and make PPCG an overall better place.

I do believe he exhibits each and every trait mentioned in [the Moderator Pro Tempore blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/), and I am quite confident that everyone here thinks that as well. It'd be a pleasure to work with him up to and perhaps through the beta period to maintain and improve our little corner of the Internet.

Also, thanks @ChrisJester-Young for all the work you did in "the early days" of the site! Congrats on your new position at Stack Exchange, and may unicorns and waffles fill your days. ;)

Comment: The question is, does Martin actually *want* to be a moderator? (Just sayin. Not everyone would.)

Comment: Well... wow... the kind words and support are a bit overwhelming. (And I'm very impressed that both of you took care to use the umlaut in my name. ;)) I'm happy to accept the nomination, as long as nobody expects me to do much moderator-y stuff before next Monday... I've got a thesis to finish. :)

Comment: @MartinBüttner Umlauts are, thankfully, very easy to type in OSX. ;-) Good luck with your thesis!

Comment: I saw the first sentence and the vote count and thought, "What is the world coming to??? People don't want Martin as the moderator?!" Then I read the rest of the post. +1, I agree with you 200%.