# The Curious Case Of The Missing Chris Jester-Young, Welcome Martin Büttner!

Tags: discussion, moderators

You arrived to the site today and noticed that something was different; something was gone and something new was in its place, but somewhat out of place, like on the wrong side of the room. You'd had hangovers like this previously but you couldn't recall chasing any absynthe the night before, all of the elephants seemed to be their usual boring color - something wasn't right.

And then it dawned on you, there's someone *new* that seems to be in charge, and someone that used to be in charge isn't in charge anymore. Immediately, you thought of blaming [Chris Jester-Young](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3/chris-jester-young), but then realized that *he, in fact, was the one that went missing*.

Chris has, indeed, joined the ranks of our core developers in order to bring the secrets he discovered from his backyard [Soylent Green](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soylent_Green) distillery into the software we all know and (usually) love. Taking his place, by [popular demand](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4929/replacement-moderator-proposal) is Martin Büttner:

[image: profile for Martin Büttner at Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Meta Stack Exchange, Q&A about the site for programming puzzle enthusiasts and code golfers]

Martin joins the ranks of our moderation team starting today, following a *very* long and reckless trail of helpfulness, beguiling competency, a frightening lack of cynicism and a demonstrated desire to lead. We should totally give that user a diamond and see what they do with it. So we did.

Please join me in giving Martin a warm welcome, we're *very* excited to be working with him,  to the extent that we even hired Chris to make it possible.

Welcome, Martin!

Comment: Hooray! \o/ Again, congrats on your new job Chris Jester-Young, and welcome to the mod team Martin!

Comment: Thank you for the kind words, and all the best to Chris! I'll try my best to fill his place as good as I can. ;)

Comment: Congratulations to both of you!

Comment: You weren't already a mod? Huh, I had just kind of assumed. :)

Comment: Well, finally!.

Comment: Eh, reviews look ok.

Comment: Can someone answer this so it stops hogging the top unanswered spot?